# How to include frequency factor in Linear SVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svc

I am using linear svc (scikit learn) for classification into news categories such as sports,health,world,technology,lifestyle. Now for a given piece of text suppose it has :
1) 5 occurrences of word windows and 3 occurrences of word machine it not classifying into technology but if i use same text and increase occurrences of windows to 12 and machine to 10 it gets classified into technology.

So is there a way to increase importance of any relevant word of class in linear svc ?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for TF-IDF . Here TF stands for Term frequency, i.e  `(Count of a term in a document)/(Total Number of terms in a document)`. This will help you to get the most frequent terms in a document. However, it might be the case that some terms which occur less frequently might be more important for classification ( or say have more weightage for classificiation). In that case, you include Inverse Document Frequency (IDF). It is calculated as `log(Total documents/(Number of documents containing a certain term, say 'x')`

Then finally you multiply Tf*IDF value to get the TF-IDF of the term.

Here is short [example at this link](http://www.tfidf.com/).

Here is an [example using scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#evaluation-of-the-performance-on-the-test-set)

References:

- [Text Feature Extraction](http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/09/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-i/)
- [Finding Important words using TF-IDF](https://stevenloria.com/tf-idf/)

Comment: I am already using TFIDF vectorizer but i need to increase weightage of some specific term, is it possible to explicitly increase the importance of some words ?

Comment: I think you need to modify different parameters of the classifier instead of modifying the data itself using grid-search, etc. I can explain it better if you could post your code .